# Calculate $\int_{[a,b]}\frac{1}{x+\ln(x)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate $$\int_{[a,b]}\frac{1}{x+\ln(x)}dx$$

Question: Is it non elementary integral?

I was trying to solve it using elementary methods, but I can't solve it. Wolfram also does not provide a solution.
Any way to solve it using complex analysis methods?

Comment: probably. Most integrals are, and this looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add another answer to this. This answer is nothing but a correction to my previous one, for I have noticed I made a huge mistake. The procedure is correct, however I missed a term.

I want to leave my other answer, so people can really see how easy can be to obtain a result which might be really close to the true one, yet it is not correct. Take this as a comparison.

The error in the procedure is when, by substituting $x \to e^y$ I miswrote the next term. Indeed $\ln(x)$ becomes $\ln(e^y) = y$, not $1$ as I wrote. I will start from here, following the same passages, after having made th substitution and arranged the integral.

$$\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} \frac{1}{1 + ye^{-y}}\ \text{d}y$$

Geometric Series, with the condition $|y e^{-y}| << 1$ gives

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} y^k e^{-ky}\ \text{d}y$$

Now the problem is that the integral is not that trivial anymore. Yet it's still doable. Actually here one needs a good knowledge of Special Functions (like Euler Gamma and Beta, the Error Functions, The Exponential Integral function and so on, you can find everything on internet and on good books).

The generic integral is solved in terms of the Incomplete Gamma Function $\Gamma(\cdot,\ \cdot)$:

$$\int y^k e^{-ky}\ \text{d}y = -\frac{\Gamma (k+1,k y)}{k^{k+1}}$$

(More about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

There are actually two types of incomplete Gamma: our is the "upper" incomplete.

Anyway this can be also written in terms of the Exponential Integral Function as follow (it's really an equivalence):

$$\int y^k e^{-ky}\ \text{d}y = -y^{k+1} E_{-k}(k y)$$

(More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Anyway, in both cases we can then solve the definite integral, getting:

$$\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} y^k e^{-ky}\ \text{d}y = \log ^{k+1}(a) E_{-k}(k \log (a))-\log ^{k+1}(b) E_{-k}(k \log (b))$$

(It comes easier in terms of the ExpInt).

Eventually

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \left(\log ^{k+1}(a) E_{-k}(k \log (a))-\log ^{k+1}(b) E_{-k}(k \log (b))\right)$$

Is a rather complicated sum. In addition to that, there is a singularity at $k  =0$.

I am not able to go further, for the moment. I take the time and the possibility to edit THIS answer futurely.

(P.s. The error I made in the first answer doesn't sound that bad now, uh?)

Answer (score -1):

We can really attack it in a simple way.

$$x \to e^y ~~~~~~~ \text{d}x = e^y\ \text{d}y$$

The integral runs from $a$ to $b$, hence the new extrema will be $\ln(a)$ and $\ln(b)$, provided that $a, b$ are real numbers. In the case of one of the two being zero, then you would get the limit $\ln(a\to 0^+) = -\infty$.

The integral is now

$$\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} \frac{e^y}{e^y + 1}\ \text{d}y$$

Which can be easily arrange into

$$\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} \frac{1}{(1 + e^{-y})}\ \text{d}y$$

The following steps hold only if it is guaranteed the condition $|e^{-y}| << 1$.

We develop the denominator in Geometric Series

$$\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k e^{-ky} \text{d}y$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k\int_{\ln(a)}^{\ln(b)}e^{-ky} \text{d}y$$

The integral is now trivial:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \frac{a^{-k}-b^{-k}}{k}$$

The series has a well known close form, so we are done:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \frac{a^{-k}-b^{-k}}{k} = \boxed{\log \left(\frac{b+1}{a+1}\right)}$$

---

Notice that this works, numerically, really well in general. Suppose you want to evaluate

$$\int_2^4 \frac{1}{x + \ln(x)}\ \text{d}x$$

Via computer programming we obtain the numerical result: $0.509426(...)$.

Let's now apply our final relation with $a = 2$ and $b = 4$:

$$\log \left(\frac{b+1}{a+1}\right) \to \log \left(\frac{4+1}{2+1}\right) \approx 0.510826(...)$$

---

Let's do another one:

$$\int_{127}^{1009} \frac{1}{x + \ln(x)}\ \text{d}x$$

The numerical correct result is $2.0352(...)$, whilst our result gives

$$\log \left(\frac{b+1}{a+1}\right) \to \log \left(\frac{1009+1}{127+1}\right) \approx 2.06568(...)$$

Works good uh?

Comment: Why are your numerical results so poor? The integrand is well-behaved over your ranges of integration.

Comment: @TonyK I will check again, in case of something I miss!

Comment: @TonyK Error Spotted. I am going to correct. Instead I am going to post a new correct answer. Thank you.